# Detect change from previous column in a dataframe to new output

Tags: r

I've searched and can't find anything that answers this question- sorry if it has been answered before!

I have data where the row values increase cumulatively. I want to be able to detect in which columns these values increase and output a new dataframe of the same size that gives 1 when the value changes and 0 when it doesn't.

Example data-

```
a<- c(0,0,0,0,0)
b<- c(1,0,0,1,0)
c<- c(2,1,0,1,1)
d<- c(3,2,0,1,2)
e<- c(4,2,1,1,2)
df<- data.frame(a,b,c,d,e)
df

a b c d e
1 0 1 2 3 4
2 0 0 1 2 2
3 0 0 0 0 1
4 0 1 1 1 1
5 0 0 1 2 2
```

Desired output-

```
  ad bd cd dd ed
1  0  1  1  1  1
2  0  0  1  1  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  0  1  0  0  0
5  0  0  1  1  0
```

I've tried ideas along the lines of-

```
 dfNew<- lapply(ifelse(df>=identical[,c(x)], 1, 0))
```

But obviously this doesn't work (I'm a bit of a rookie). Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Your first column will always be 0 right? also the increase will be always by 1 each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is to get the row wise difference, `rowDiffs` from `matrixStats` can be used

```
library(matrixStats)
`colnames<-`(cbind(df[1],rowDiffs(as.matrix(df))),
                     paste0(names(df), "d"))
#  ad bd cd dd ed
#1  0  1  1  1  1
#2  0  0  1  1  0
#3  0  0  0  0  1
#4  0  1  0  0  0
#5  0  0  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by finding the `diff` rowwise?

```
cbind(a = 0, t(apply(df, 1, diff)))
#     a b c d e
#[1,] 0 1 1 1 1
#[2,] 0 0 1 1 0
#[3,] 0 0 0 0 1
#[4,] 0 1 0 0 0
#[5,] 0 0 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the main bit of work

```
+sapply(2:ncol(df), function(i) df[,i]>df[,i-1])
```

It will return a matrix, and you will need to fix the column names

Comment: Thanks for the help!